# Weird lines between meshes in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a Minecraft clone for fun, and I encountered a problem that shouldn't happen. When I generated the meshes, I didn't make any gaps between the quads. But for some reason, a thin line appeared between the quads.

[image]

And it is one piece of mesh, not separated. I don't understand why that happened.
Can someone please help?

**Edit:** *the gaps aren't as obvious in the scene view.*

**Edit 2:** *The gaps aren't as obvious when the MSAA of the camera is turned off.*

Comment: These issue are usually related to mipmaps. Try to turn it off on the textures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the way 3d rendering works, it is difficult to completely get rid of the lines. If you are never supposed to see the side texture anyways, I would suggest deleting the sides of the mesh. If that is not an option, try increasing both the near and far culling planes of your camera, as increasing them reduces depth artifacts.

i think a simple google search might have done the trick. The answer that i just gave u, i found on the internet on the unity forums.